# How to globally prefix all css rules generated by styled-components 5.3.5 with a parent class

Tags: css, reactjs, babeljs, styled-components

My app will be loaded into a parent div that has a specific class (e.g. `.my-app`).

Is there a way to preprend all the classes generated by styled-components with `.my-app` .

Given a component like

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = (props) => {
  return <StyledButton type="button">foo</StyledButton>;
};

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: blue;
`;

export default Button;
```

normally you might have output like

```html
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.1.1">
    .cuetwY { color: blue; }
</style>
<div class="my-app">
    <button class="cuetwY">foo</button>
</div>
```

But I'm trying to achieve the following:

```html
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.1.1">
    /* Note the additional selector prepended here */
    .my-app .cuetwY { color: blue; }
</style>
<div class="my-app">
    <button class="cuetwY">foo</button>
</div>
```

I have tried both [babel-plugin-styled-components-css-namespace](https://github.com/QuickBase/babel-plugin-styled-components-css-namespace) and [stylis-plugin-extra-scope](https://github.com/Andarist/stylis-plugin-extra-scope) but neither seems to work with newer versions of styled-components and the older versions of sc don't work with React 18.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to set your own class / classes in a component using **styled-components**. In this case, using the **attrs** method you can set your custom class.

> This is a chainable method that attaches some props to a styled component. The first and only argument is an object that will be merged into the rest of the component's props. The attrs object accepts the following values: [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const Style = styled.button.attrs((props) => ({
  className: `my-${props.random}`
}))`
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
`;

export const Button = () => {
  const generatedStyleName = "DweDw32FS";
  return <Style random={generatedStyleName}>Click me</Style>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. I'm happy for the style names to be random strings, but I want each style definition to have my class prepended (to add specificity)

Comment: @marmite You can pass generated value to your class with **props**. I've updated snippet.

Comment: thanks again for trying to help but I'm not trying to add a class name to the html element, I'm trying to prepend a parent class to the style definition in the CSS that style-components generates

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a `Namespace` for all of your classes using `babel-plugin-styled-components`(https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components) config. As described over here https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#namespace